# Memory error in the code and possible solution

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

Although the code is compiling and displaying the output correctly, yet when I ran "valgrind", it showed the following error. It is very difficult for me to understand this since I don't have any background in valgrind.

```
Invalid write of size 1
==14657==    at 0x4EAE10C: _IO_default_xsputn (genops.c:480)
==14657==    by 0x4E7CF81: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1630)
==14657==    by 0x4EA3813: vsprintf (iovsprintf.c:43)
==14657==    by 0x4E85A06: sprintf (sprintf.c:34)
==14657==    by 0x400622: copy_id_name (assign2a.c:12)
==14657==    by 0x40065E: main (assign2a.c:21)
==14657==  Address 0x51f204b is 0 bytes after a block of size 11 alloc'd
==14657==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14657==    by 0x400600: copy_id_name (assign2a.c:11)
==14657==    by 0x40065E: main (assign2a.c:21)
==14657==
```

Please explain me the actual error and what is the solution to remove this error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/** Returns a pointer to allocated memory containing string in form "<id>=<name>" */
char *copy_id_name(const char *id, const char *name) {
    char *ptr = NULL;
    size_t len;
    // Compute required length
    len = strlen(id) + strlen(name);    // [sic]
    ptr = malloc(len-2);    // [sic]
    sprintf(ptr, "%s=%s", id, name);
    return ptr;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ptr;

    if (argc > 2) {
    ptr = copy_id_name(argv[1], argv[2]);
    } else {
    ptr = copy_id_name("666", "badname");
    }
    printf("result: [%s]\n", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are your valgrind options?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have to remember that strings in C are actually one character longer than reported by `strlen`. That extra character is use for a special character (`'\0'`) that tells function that it's the end of the string.

The problem here is that you are allocating two bytes *less* than the combined length of the `id` and `name` strings, and then you combine those strings with two *added* characters (the `'='` and the terminating `'\0'`). That means you will write beyond the end of the allocated memory.

Comment: Even after change from malloc(len) to malloc(len+2), the valgrind is displaying the same error as mentioned above :(

Comment: @user3425724 Just to verify, in your program add a debug `printf` call printing the size you allocate (e.g. `printf("allocating %d bytes\n", len + 2);`). If the length is not `12` (with the strings `"666"` and `"badname"` as in your example) then you don't show us the correct code.

Comment: was running the wrong file. Problem resolved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 ptr = malloc(len-2);
```

You allocate 4 bytes less than needed. strlen() gives the length of a string and does not count null termination. You need to allocate space for the null termination, however. Simply change the -2 to +2.

Comment: Even after change from malloc(len) to malloc(len+2), the valgrind is displaying the same error as mentioned above :(